# 1970/80s Jules Verne-inspired bizarre underwater city / submarine abduction

Tags: identify-this-movie, fantasy

I am looking for a movie I saw as a child in the 1980s on German TV. Sadly my memory is somewhat blurrish.

I remember a "20000 leagues under the sea"-inspired story, featuring the main characters being abducted into a submarine or underwater city.

It was a live-action color movie with a distinct steam fantasy feel. Most likely not a German but a dubbed foreign movie, and I remember a rather high production value. Likely made in the 1970s or 1980s.

I most dominantly remember that it featured antagonists with large, bizarre *moustaches*. The most memorable image is that in the end, a lot of people die in an over-the-top (still suitable for minors) fashion, with one being *pierced by a cello or double bass*.

The whole movie had a humorous but also rather grotesque, silent-film-era feeling to it.

I'm afraid that's all I have to go on. Any hints appreciated.

**Update:** Given the considerable difficulty in finding this movie, it is quite possible that it was a former Eastern Bloc production. The closest I could find in tone and style is *Vynález zkázy* (*The Fabulous World of Jules Verne*) from 1958 ([IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052374/), [Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5vc4rgjdhw)), but that is not it.

**Update:** It is none of the works listed at Wikipedias' [*Adaptations of Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptations_of_Twenty_Thousand_Leagues_Under_the_Sea).

Comment: Try "Jules Verne" as [imdb's  keyword](http://www.imdb.com/search/keyword?keywords=jules-verne&sort=moviemeter,asc&mode=detail&page=1&release_date=1950%2C1990&ref_=kw_ref_yr)

Comment: `one being pierced by a cello or double bass` reminds me of a Monty Python sketch - Sam Peckinpah's salad days (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmcrreUVBeo)

Comment: The League of Extrordinary Gentlemen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_League_of_Extraordinary_Gentlemen_(film)) feature Nautilus, the submarine and it's captain from *20000 leagues under the sea*. It's my closest guess considering the moustaches and the high production value, but it was rather recent. Hope that helps :)

Comment: @hrishioa I could not possibly have seen a 2003-released film in the 1980s.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptations_of_Twenty_Thousand_Leagues_Under_the_Sea -- Any of these?

Comment: @SeanR No. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "[Tajemství Hradu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OymtX2R52os)" (otherwise known as ["The Mysterious Castle in the Carpathians"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Castle_in_the_Carpathians)).

It's Jules Verne inspired, the characters have amazing moustaches and there's a scene involving a cello spike being used to murder one of the characters...

[image]

Comment: Words fail me. Unbelievable, yes, that is absolutely it. Thanks a ton! Okay so it wasn't a submarine after all, but then again, all I had was a memory 30 years old. Faith in the internet in general and movies.stackexchange restored. :-)